# Как из словаря с ключем забрать список Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, массивы, dict

У меня есть словарь, внутри которого есть список. Мне нужно забрать этот список  и вывести всё на страницу в красивом виде.

Если что словарь приходит из Backend Django

Вот что прилетает в **console.log**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это то, что в **терминале**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай вот мой **views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 import json

 def index(request):
 spisok = main.start.lists
 data = {
     'count': spisok,
 }
 var = json.dumps(data)
 context = {"count":var}

 print(var)
 return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

И ещё **index.html**

```
<div class="content">
<div class="task" id="span-task"></div>
<br>
<button class="btn-next" id="next-button">Проверить</button>
{% comment %} <script>console.log({{count|safe}}) </script> {% endcomment %}
<script>
var data = {{count|safe}}
GetTask(data)
</script>
</div>
```

Как всё это сделать на JavaScript не знаю

Comment: Можно убрать json.dumps(), передать словарь и пробежаться с помощью джанго циклом for по этому словарю, выводя данные в нужном форматировании. См. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 0):

У вас приходит ответ от сервера в виде объекта, свойство `count` которого имеет значение массива. Я написал функцию, которая принимает аргумент в виде массива, проходится по нему встроенным методом массивов `forEach()`, добавляя содержимое каждого элемента массива в элемент списка `#tasks` в макете HTML при нажатии кнопки.

При нажатии кнопки срабатывает событие `onclick` (описать действия при событии можно в атрибуте, либо в самом js как `document.querySelector(ваш_селектор).onclick`) и запускается функция с нужным аргументом, у меня это свойство объекта `obj` (obj.count), а у вас это будет выглядеть как `data.count`, если вы ответ помещаете в переменную data.

Чтобы избежать ошибок последовательности исполнения скриптов, я добавил проверку на тип данных у аргумента функции (`null` является объектом в JavaScript, однако это ошибка языка). В примере есть строчки, которые вам не нужны, они для имитации ответа сервера.

Справка:

[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
[DOM Events](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp)
[querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
[Типа данных JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/types)

```js
//строчки, которые вам нужно удалить, это для воспроизведения примера
let obj = {
  count: ['9 + 6', '5 + 3 ', '1 + 7', '7 + 10']
}
//строчки, которые вам нужно удалить, это для воспроизведения примера

function getTask(data) {
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
    let i = 0;
    document.querySelector('#next-button').onclick = ()=> {
      if(i < data.length) {
        document.querySelectorAll('#tasks li')[i].innerHTML = data[i];
        i++;
      }  
    };
    
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

getTask(obj.count);
```

```html
<button class="btn-next" id="next-button">Проверить</button>

<ul id="tasks">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li> 
</ul>

<script>
//var data = {{count|safe}}
//GetTask(data)
</script>
```

Comment: Привет! Спасибо тебе огромное за подсказку, всё получилось, если у тебя есть время, поможешь сделать так, чтобы массив не сразу весь выводился, а элементы выводились по очереди.

Comment: @Danil то есть одно нажатие кнопки - вывод одного элемента?

Comment: Абсолютно верно !

Comment: @Danil актуально еще? переписал код